# How to derive parts of a type/class into an interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Consider,

```js
class someClass1 {
key1: string,
key2: number,
key3: someType1,
}
```

I need an interface which has only the keys key1 and key3

```js
interface someInterface1{
key1: string,
key3: someType1
}
```

But now if I update the class someClass1's key1 type to number, I will have to manually update someInterface1 key1 to number.

I do not want to do this manually.

Can we write code so that such redundancy does not exist?

P.S. someClass1 in my case is a entity corresponding to a table in SQL database.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys?

Comment: @jonrsharpe would you write up an answer here?  Or would the OP like to do it themself?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your interface in class and just declare properties without type inside your class;

```
interface someInterface1{
    key1: string;
    key3: someType1;
}
class someClass1 implements someInterface1 {
    declare key1;
    key2: number;
    declare key3;
}
```

Comment: Though that is a solution, I cannot change someClass1 because it is logically an entity mapped to an sql table. The pick<> method works perfectly here.